# How can I have my angular component update when new data is added to sessionStorage?

Tags: angular

I'm using a service to communicate between two components. The idea is that when I click 'add to clipboard' on component A, this gets added to sessionStorage. Component B should then retrieve it and update the view.

I've managed to get most of it working so that my items appear in Component B and persist - but only after the page is reset. How can I have Component B refresh each time something is added.

**method in component A (sender)**

```
  addToClipboard() {

    let item: Item = {id : this.itemId, collection : this.collectionName, database : this.dbName, name: itemTitle };

    this.clipboardService.addItemToClipboard(item);
  }
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClipboardService {

  // items$: Observable<Item []>;
  // private itemSubject = new Subject<Item []>();

  constructor() {
    // this.items$ = this.itemSubject.asObservable();
  }

  addItemToClipboard(item: Item) {
    console.log(item);
    // this.itemSubject.next(item);
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('clipItems') !==  null) {
      console.log(sessionStorage.length);
      const storedItems: Item [] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clipItems'));
      storedItems.push(item);
      sessionStorage.setItem('clipItems', JSON.stringify(storedItems));
    } else {
      const items: Item [] = [];
      items.push(item);
      sessionStorage.setItem('clipItems', JSON.stringify(items));
    }
  }

  getItemsFromClipBoard(): Item [] {
    const storedItems: Item [] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clipItems'));
    return storedItems;
  }

}
```

**component B (reciever)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from 'src/app/models/item';
import { ClipboardService } from '../clipboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clipboard',
  templateUrl: './clipboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clipboard.component.css'],
})
export class ClipboardComponent implements OnInit {

  items: Item [] = [];

  constructor(private clipboardService: ClipboardService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.clipboardService.getItemsFromClipBoard();
  }

}
```

Ideally, every time the 'items' list refreshes I'd like to update the component (I've had to use session in the service because the items need to persist until the user logs out).

Comment: You should communicate via services, not storages. Just emit some kind of event via Subjects when you change the item in the storage.

Comment: If the items were stored in a service variable, they would persist anway. You could just then have a function to clear the items variable when the user logs out. No need for session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store in service variable instead of session and make available as BehaviourSubject so can be subscribed to from any component.

This will persist and you could just have a function to clear the service variable on log out if needed. e.g:

Service:

```
itemsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>(this.getItems());

addItem(item)
  {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  getItems()
  {
    return this.items;
  }
```

Component:

```
export class MyComponent
   items: Item[];

//constructor
 this.clipboardService.itemsSubject.subscribe(res =>
        {
          this.items= res;
        });
```

Some auth service:

```
LogOut()
{
   //clear session then:
   this.clipboardService.items = [];

}
```